# Can't iterate through XPathSelectorList

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, firebug

I have build the simple web-scraper below:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class ITTester(BaseSpider):
    name = 'ITTester'
    allowed_domains = ["sec.gov"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000112760212034445/xslF345X03/form4.xml']

    def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select("/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr")
    print len(sites)
    for site in sites:
        HHH = site.select("/td[1]/span[1]/text()").extract()
        print HHH
```

I goes to [this site](http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000112760212034445/xslF345X03/form4.xml) and I want to scrape and print each of the instance of "Common Stock" (that is 2 times "Common Stock").

I have identified the rows of the table with `hxs.select("/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr")` and when printing the length of the returned `XPathSelectorList` it prints 2, however the print in the `for loop` returns 2 blank brackets []. I have used Firebug to get the XPath, I have checked that the `tbody` actually is in the source code.

Any ideas to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a relative path in the inner selection so `site.select("td[1]/span[1]/text()").extract()` instead of what you have.

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm. Can you elaborate on what the difference is between having a / before and not?

Comment: Any path starting with `/` selects down from the document node so `/td[1]` selects the first `td` child element of the document node. You want the first `td` child of your `site` node, so you need to use a relative path.

Comment: Thanks! Wish I had a better understanding of Xpath :)